# Fatal: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“did you run git update-server-info” error on a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343189/did-you-run-git-update-server-info-error-on-a-github-repository)

I am running a command to clone a repository from a URL:

```
hg clone my_url
```

The URL is on the [globalit](https://globalit.fogbugz.com/) site, but I am getting the following error:

> Fatal: 'my url' not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: you're using mercurial to clone from a git repository?

Comment: @SztupY Thank you very much for your responce. But I already came accross using `mercurial` and it's working.