# What am I missing when adding a remote github branch?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I am adding a remote repository like this

```
git remote add pythonic https://github.com/sanfx/pythonic.git
```

but I get this error saying

> fatal: https://github.com/sanfx/pythonic.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Previously when I did `git push -f python3_ver2` added a remote branch even though I didn't have it on github.com.

What am I missing in adding a remote branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["did you run git update-server-info" error on a Github repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343189/did-you-run-git-update-server-info-error-on-a-github-repository)

Comment: it's a 404 for me. is it a private repo?

Comment: I mostly get this when I misspelled things.

Comment: also you're not adding a branch, you're adding a repo

Comment: well, I got it just ran `git push -u origin pythonic` created a remote branch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error simply means that Git cannot find the repository you are trying to add. This can be either because it simply does not exist on GitHub, or because it is a private repository where you don’t have access to.

If you go to https://github.com/sanfx/pythonic, you can see that GitHub is returning a 404 for the repository.

So please double check that the repository name is actually correct and that you have the necessary access rights.