# Cannot push commits to a remote repository - GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I have an Android project I was working on in Eclipse. I created an account for myself on github and pushed code within the project to the online remote repository using the GitHub for Mac client. Subsequently, I made a couple more minor commits to the code and all went well.

Now the code has undergone some significant changes and when I try to commit using the Mac client, I get the following error message on Sync:
`Sync Failed: Please commit all your changes before syncing.`

To get around this, I tried the following:
1. Tried to use `git push origin/master` from the command line. This resulted in `project/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`
2. I checked if the repository name, location etc. were all correct and they were.

My question(s):
1. There are a large number of `.class` files which show up in the Changes section. Why do they show up given that .class files are included in `.gitignore`? Now that they have shown up, is it necessary to select and commit them too?
2. What is the meaning of the error message above and how do I get rid of it?

**EDIT 1:**
After the following commands:
1. `git ls-tree -r master | grep .class` - this showed that `.class` files were also added to the repository.
2. `git rm **/*.class` to remove all `.class` files from the repository.
3. `git commit -m "remove class files`
4. `git push origin master` results in:

```
fatal: https://github.com/user/project.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Also, running `git status` on the command line shows the following line:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 16 commits.
#
```

Is this something of concern?

I have been through a lot of threads on this topic and taken a look at stuff like SSH-keygen but I dont think that is the solution to my problem. I am a newbie to git and have used only cvs before, so please dumb-down your answers, if possible.

My `.gitignore` file:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
*.class

*.class

*.class

*.jar

*.class

*.class

bin/dexedLibs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1-e5ffa87f4686586f2e03d9069f131ba3.jar

*.class
```

Comment: what is the output of `git remote show origin`?

Comment: It is again `fatal:... update-server-info`. It is a private repository. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was signed in to `GitHub`'s Mac client using a personal ID. This personal ID was not registered as a collaborator on the project. Adding my personal account as a collaborator (an ugly work-around) solved the problem. I was able to commmit changes to the repository.

Other suggestions which I found useful:
  - Removing `.class` files from the repository.
To check if `.class` files were being tracked: `git ls-tree -r master | grep .class`
To remove them from the repo and commit: `git rm **/*.class` followed by `git commit -m "your message goes here"`
To push all changes: `git push origin master`.

To be able to use `git` with multiple accounts, I found [this account here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts/) to be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to push the commits to your local repository and THEN push the commits to the remote one. This allows you to do very easy merges with the remote repository as every commit has a unique SHA id which is used to tell where your repository is in relationship to the remote repo.

do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push origin master    (NOT git push origin/master)
```

**EDIT**

Did you by chance change the name of the github repository? This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343189/did-you-run-git-update-server-info-error-on-a-github-repository) should shed some light.

Comment: I tried to push the changes to the remote repo using `git push origin master` but still end up with `update-server-info` error as above. Can you please also see the question for an edit?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have committed the .class files in the repository already. In which case git will keep tracking them even if you put *.class in the .gitignore file. Run `git ls-tree -r master | grep .class`. If that gives any output you have committed .class files. If so, try running `git rm **/*.class` and commit the change.

You are not supposed to run `git push origin/master` you need to specify a remote and then (optionally) a branch. Now git will try to parse `origin/master` as a remote. Use `git push origin master` instead (use a space not a /). `origin/master` is a branch that you should not be changing yourself anyway.

Besides you have *.class multiple times in your .gitignore. Multiple occurrences will not change the behavior of git.

Comment: You were right. the .class files were being added to the repo. I removed them as you suggested. Using `git push origin master` still does not work though. I still get the `update-server-info` error.

Comment: @Sriram What does `git remote -v` output? Did you rename the repository on github?

Comment: `git remote -v` outputs:  
`origin https://github.com/englishhelper/BlueBottle.git (fetch)  
origin https://github.com/englishhelper/BlueBottle.git (push)`  
And why should I rename the project?

Comment: You do not need to rename the repository. But if you did, that could be the reason for the error. I can not find your repository on github. Which means that either it is private (and you pay for your github account) or it does not exist. Which would explain why you get the error.

Comment: @Sriram take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406963/git-fatal-error-info-refs-not-found Something is wrong with the link to the repository. Perhaps you did not create it, typed it wrong, changed something to lowercase... Unfortunately I can not check this since it is a private repository.

Comment: I got it. I was trying to push changes to the repo using a username which was not listed as a collaborator for the project. hence the errors. which brings me to my next question: how do I manage multiple users on git?

Answer (score 0):

' git commit . '   will commit all your changes.

Maybe you can try it... ( I'm not sure, just an idea )

Comment: How do I commit changes to the remote repository? This I think will commit only to the local repository right?

Comment: Further, if I use that command, I get all `.class` and the `R.java` file in the modified section, files which were supposed to have been ignored as per `.gitignore`.

Comment: Can you post you gitignore ? In fact, if there is a line with '.class', it shouldn't treat this files...

Comment: Oki, and is your remote gitignore is the same ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.